# repl.it question "lovesPizza" in control flow coding giving me trouble

Tags: control-flow

It says that I'm missing a ";" on line 5 `else(typeOfPizza === "olives"){`

```
function exerciseThree(typeOfPizza){
  let lovesPizza;
  if (typeOfPizza === "pepperoni"){
    return "true";}
  else(typeOfPizza === "olives"){
    return "false";
  }
```

Comment: What's the question? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

Where you are using a condition for `else` it actually needs to be `else if` like this:

```
function exerciseThree(typeOfPizza){
  let lovesPizza;
  if (typeOfPizza === "pepperoni"){
    return "true";}
  else if (typeOfPizza === "olives"){
    return "false";
  }
}
```

You cannot have `else(condition)` the else if statement needs to be `if(condition) {} else {}` if you require a condition for the else then you need to do `if(condition) {} else if(condition) {}`

Comment: I tried that and it is still not working, it now is showing that the answers to the first two questions are incorrect, which I know are correct. Maybe there is a issue with this quiz?

Comment: I do not know the whole quiz, but that function, if you pass it `"pepperoni"` it will return `"true"` and if you pass `"olives"` it will return `"false"` and if you pass any other string it will return nothing.